# How to use web3.0 node_modules in Magento2?

Tags: magento2, pwa

when I use like web3, etc. get the problem is those js packages require lots of all other js from node_modules. So I think it's impossible to create a symbolic link for all of those js.I have used the reference link below.

https://docs.walletconnect.com/web3modal/javascript/about

I am also adding some code in required-config.js

```
    var config = {
    paths: {
        web3: 'VendorName_ModuleName/node_modules/@web3modal'
    }
};
```

I am also running the commands below in
path
**/var/www/html/project/app/code/VendorName/ModuleName/view/frontend/web**

```
npm install @web3modal/ethers5 ethers@5.7.2
```

so please help me how connect wallet web 3.0.

Comment: Yes, I also find similar solutions on how to connect the crypto wallet to the Magento through the custom extension. if you get any solution please reach me out.